# Younger Class of Students

Tags: expressions

What is the expression to refer to a "younger class of students".

Specifically, for instance I entered my university in 2002, and there a pool of students entering university of in 2004. How should I address, for instance, this pool of students. 
Is a "younger class of students" a right way to say?

Comment: Undergraduate students who have only just entered university (eg they're in their first week) are *freshers*. (BrEng)

Comment: Maybe _freshman_ without reference to any year. I personally like _cohort_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most students who entered university in 2004 would be younger than those who entered in 2002, but there will probably be some older late-entry students.

For this reason, unless the age of the students who entered in 2004 is central to your writing, I suggest:

"newer intake of students" or  "more recent intake of students" or, if the date is important, "2004 intake of students".

Answer (score 0):

I would use "later class of students" or use a term that indicates how much time has passed since they started at the university.   For example:

**first year students**

**second year students**

**third year students**